# how to give read only access to the xml file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, linq

how to give read only access to the xml file in c#?

Comment: you may want to provide a little more detail if you don't want a downvote and possible closure.

Comment: Silly comment but.... 
Print the xml file then the only access one could have is read-only.

Comment: @ggonsalv I still could scribble on it :P

Comment: Funny, guess I need some coffee...........

Answer (score 7):

This code will help :-

```
using System.IO;

FileInfo flInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\alok.txt"); // load file
flInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.ReadOnly; // set file attribute
```